# Save and load QList<Class*> to file

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qdatastream

I have a class ContactData and a class FriendList holding a QList and I overloaded the << / >> operators.

---

*contactdata.h*

```
class ContactData
{
//all public for testing
public:
    ContactData();
    QString m_name;
    QString m_description;
    bool m_online; 
};

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& out, ContactData& contactData);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& in, ContactData* contactData);
```

*contactdata.cpp*

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, ContactData& contactData)
{
    out << contactData.m_name;
    out << contactData.m_description;
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, ContactData* contactData)
{
    in >> contactData->m_name;
    in >> contactData->m_description;
    return in;
}
```

---

*friendlist.h*

```
#include "contactdata.h"
typedef QList<ContactData*> TFriendList;

class FriendList
{
...
public:
TFriendList* m_list;
...
};

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& out, FriendList& list);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& in, FriendList* list);
```

*friendlist.cpp*

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& out, FriendList& list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        ContactData contact = *list.at(i);
        out << contact;
    }

    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& in, FriendList* list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++)
    {
        ContactData* contact = list->m_list->at(i);
        in >> contact;
    }

    return in;
}
```

---

```
// typedef QList<ContactData*> TFriendList;
private:
    FriendList* m_friendList;
```

*saving function*

```
QString path = "/friendlist.bin";
QFile file(path);

if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << m_friendList;
    file.close();
}
```

*loading function*

```
QString path = "/friendlist.bin";
QFile file(path);
if(file.exists())
{
  if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
  {
     QDataStream in(&file);
     in >> m_friendList;
     file.close();
     qDebug() << "FriendList.size() = " << m_friendList->size();
     }
}
```

---

It does save a file in the desired direction, but unfortunately loading gives me an empty list of the size 0.
This is where I'm stuck..

Can anyone help?

Comment: From your code: for(int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++) to deserialize list itself. when list is empty (and you want to load it) size() will return 0 so nothing will be deserialized. You have to (try to) deserialize until stream is ended (or write list size at beginning).

Comment: You have error in your code. Your << operator expects `FriendList &` but you give `FriendList *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code to rebuild list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++)
```

Problem is that when you're deserializing into an empty list `size()` will return 0 (or a value completely unrelated to what you have to read from disk) and anyway you have to read items from stream, it doesn't matter actual list size. Moreoverlist is empty so you have first to create a new element (you can't just call `at()` because there aren't elements inside). You can write an integer (for example) before items then read it when deserializing:

```
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& in, FriendList* list)
{
    int count = 0;
    in >> count;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ContactData* contact = new ContactData();
        in >> contact;

        list->m_list->push_back(contact);
    }

    return in;
}
```

Do not forget to write `count` in serialization function too. As alternative you may read everything until end of input stream:

```
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& in, FriendList* list)
{
    int count = 0;
    in >> count;

    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        ContactData* contact = new ContactData();
        in >> contact;

        list->m_list->push_back(contact);
    }

    return in;
}
```

To finish check what [Kamil said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186434/save-and-load-qlistclass-to-file/21186634#comment31898639_21186434) in comment, if you don't have any error during serialization probably it's just a typo but...

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to overload the `>>` and `<<` operators for `QList`, they already exist when the left-hand operator is `QDataStream`

see [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-lt-lt-68)

As long as an individual object can serialise and deserialise correctly, all Qt containers should also serialise and deserialise.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who submitted help, now it works fine to me. 
For those who are interested, here is what I had to change:

*saving function*

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << *m_friendList;
    file.close();
}
```

*friendlist.cpp*

```
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& in, FriendList* list)
{
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        ContactData* contact = new ContactData();
        in >> contact;
        list->m_list->push_back(contact);
    }
    return in;
}
```